# How to use strftime in jalali date in python?

Tags: python

I need convert ''1396/4/28'' to ''1396/04/28'' in persian date.

Code:

```
from service import jalali
now_date = datetime.datetime.now() // 2017-07-19 21:32:34.574369
date = now_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') // 2017-07-19
from_date = jalali.Gregorian(date).persian_string("{}/{}/{}") // '1396/4/28'
```

How to convert ''1396/4/28'' to ''1396/04/28'' in persian date in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime
from service import jalali

from_date = jalali.Gregorian(date).persian_string("{}/{}/{}")
print datetime.strptime('1396/4/28', '%Y/%m/%d')
print datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y/%m/%d')

> datetime.datetime(1396, 4, 28, 0, 0)
> datetime.datetime(1396, 4, 28, 0, 0)
```

If you mean how to print a date like this with `strftime` - that is not possible for dates <1900. Print it manually instead:

```
print ("%04d/%02d/%02d" % (date.year, date.month, date.day))

> 1396/04/28
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PersianTools](https://pypi.org/project/persiantools/):

```python
from persiantools.jdatetime import JalaliDateTime
import datetime

now_date = datetime.datetime.now() # datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 11, 15, 1, 57, 256596)
from_date = JalaliDateTime.to_jalali(now_date) # JalaliDateTime(1399, 11, 23, 15, 1, 57, 256596)
from_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") # '1399/11/23'
```